# ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) change html code if condition is true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm working on ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) project. I want to display `HTML` code if the condition is true but it's seems like the browser is showing it as `Plain Text` instead of `HTML` code.

Here is my **HTML** **:**

```
<li>@(active=="test" ? "<a href='?log' id='button'>TEST</a>" : "<a href='?test' id='button'>TEST</a>")</li>
```

I want if `@(active=="test")` condition is true then my `HTML` code change to another. Please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this

```
<li>@Html.Raw(active=="test" ?"<a href='?log' id='button'>TEST</a>" : "<a href='?test' id='button'>TEST</a>")</li>
```

The point is Razor always encodes output, you need to tell it not to do it using Html.Raw() helper

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
@if(active=="test")
{
<a href='?log' id='button'>TEST</a>
}
else
{
<a href='?test' id='button'>TEST</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks It's working! But I want to know also how it's working now and what's wrong with my method?

Comment: Razor does not recognize the '?' operator so it just renders it as plain text. Razorview engine has its ups and downs.

Comment: Because browser source code showing the same result with both methods.

Comment: OKK... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MaryMelody With this approach, Razor stops processing when it meets '<' and just outputs the tag. What you did was you gave it a string not a tag.